# .sh script for counting the number of names in a category in a .csv

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, csv

I would like to count the number of students in a .csv file depending on the category

Category 1 is the name, Category 2 is the country, Category 3 is the city

The .csv file is displayed as such :

```
michael_s;jpa;NYC
john_d;chn;TXS
jim_h;usa;POP
```

When I execute the script like

```
cat students.csv | ./script.sh PAR
```

It should only display the number of students in PAR but also when I execute the script it can also display other cities such as NYC, PAR, etc

What I have done:

```
cut -d";" -f3 students.csv | sort | uniq -c
```

It works as attended but I need it to display other cities as well when executing the script with another city after it

```
cat students.csv | ./script.sh PAR

133 NYC
```

or

```
cat students.csv | ./script.sh NYC

107 NYC
```

Comment: `cut -d";" -f3 students.csv | grep $1 | sort | uniq -c` is a naive approach which would work if the value (i.e PAR) isn't anywhere else in the csv file. Is that good enough?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this...

```
cat students.csv | grep $1 |wc -l
```

That could go into a script an be run as:

```
./myscript.sh NYC
```

Your whole script would look like:

```
#/bin/bash
cat students.csv | grep $1 |wc -l
```

To get the name of the city on the line with the count you can use:

```
cat student.csv|grep $1|printf "$1 $(wc -l) \n"
```